# 'Advised me to..' vs 'Advised me that I..'

Tags: grammar

Which one is correct?

He advised me to see the doctor.

He advised me that I see the doctor.

Comment: I'm not sure that a verb can have two direct objects like the second example. It certainly sounds odd.

Comment: Presumably you have seen these examples in use somewhere. Are you sure the second one wasn't "He advised me that I _should_ see the doctor"? That form is used quite frequently, I've never seen it without the "should".

Comment: English is different in how it uses subordinate clauses.  It is more common in this format to use the infinitive than it is with "that"

Comment: I asked him who the person in front of me was. He advised me that I see the doctor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are correct, but the second sentence is not a common way of speaking as @AndrewLeach pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

"...advised that I [do something]" is an example of what is commonly caused the subjunctive mood in English. In this case, *do* is an infinitive form, even with perhaps odd verbs like *be:* "He advised that I be quiet." Using a *that*-clause, *advise* is still a transitive verb, and the *that*-clause is what is advised: it's the direct object.

If you use *me,* as in "He advised me [to do something]" then *me* is the direct object.

The two direct objects are slightly different: in the first, the advice which is given is the object; in the second, the recipient is the object. It's similar to the way a verb like *to tell* works.

I believe the reason the first is right and the second sounds wrong is because of the objects of the verb. You can't have two direct objects, and *advise* doesn't take an indirect object like *give* does.

"He gave me a parcel" has *parcel* as the direct object and *me* is the indirect object. You can reword that sentence as "He gave a parcel to me" to make that distinction explicit. There is no similar construction for *advise,* so attempting to use *advise* in that way, with an indirect object, doesn't work.

Thus the first is right, and the second wrong.

Comment: The second is not wrong. It just means something else.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Write an answer explaining that. I don't see it.

Comment: I wrote a comment to the question.

Comment: Yes. Please explain how that works, and why it's not the same as the first sentence (which I believe the question intends it to be).

Comment: In the first sentence, he gave me an advice to see the doctor. In the second sentence, he informed me that what I see is the doctor.

Comment: Don't answer in comments. Write an answer explaining the difference for the OP.

Comment: It's not an answer. It's a comment.

Comment: Maybe there's a U.S.–U.K. difference. I don't see anything wrong with *He advised me that I was under arrest,* which your reasoning would also say was ungrammatical. [See Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=advised+me+that+I+was%3Aeng_us_2012%2Cadvised+me+that+I+was%3Aeng_gb_2012&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cadvised%20me%20that%20I%20was%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cadvised%20me%20that%20I%20was%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0). And you certainly can't say *He advised that I was under arrest to me.*